# hiding or camouflaging software

Tags: desktop-customization, package-management

We are a small IT service provider and are planning to provide a VPN service to one of our customers. 
Since another rival IT service provider also has access to our customer's laptops and if they can identify which VPN product we are using, they can easily copy our service and start competing with us.

So I am looking for ways to prevent this by hiding or camouflaging the client which will be installed on the laptops. 
I am open to other ideas to achieve our main objective, to keep our rivals from replicating our service.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: You may need to do this in hardware (a VPN controller on their LAN), not in software, as Windows was not designed to keep this from admin level users.

Comment: How and why does your competitor have access to you customer's laptops? For what purpose is that happening? Maybe that doesn't matter to the question or answer really, but that itself sounds like a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to hide your program that a good developer cannot
crack. If you succeed too much in doing that, you risk your product being
tagged as malware by some anti-virus and then you are finished.

If you are worried about your product being used without your license,
you may search for "protect license managers".
These are programs that will demand some authentication that only you can
provide for one installation at a time.

You will be safe as long as you don't succeed too much and tempt one of the best hackers around.